# Error whenever a java applet is loaded

Tags: java, applet

For the past few months or so, I've been getting an error whenever I attempt to use a java applet.
I'm getting this error on every browser I use, and I get the error occasionally in linux, too.
The java applet loads for roughly 5 seconds or so, then it stops and I get two error messages, stating that an exception occurred (`java.io.EOFException`).
This seems to happen regardless of what website I'm using. Going to the website shows I'm running java 6 update 20, and I get no error. Googling the error turns up nothing useful - I'm not a java developer, so most of the results don't apply to me at all.
My question is this. What's causing this error, and what can I do to fix whatever issue is causing it?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I put the full error log from the java console onto pastie. http://pastie.org/995769

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I looked further, turns out I had to delete the trusted.certs file under ~/Application Data/Sun/Java/Deployment/Security (~/.java/deployment/security in linux). That solved the problem.